# Can two laptops communicate when each is connected to an Android phone via USB tethering?

Tags: android, ip, usb, tethering, rndis

I have two laptop. One of them is a server, while the other is a clint. Each laptop is connected to an Android phone with its own SIM card via USB tethering. Both simcards are from the same service provider. Both phones can ping each other, but when I connect to the laptop through USB tethering, the phone creates a new interface **rndis0** with its own DHCP server, which assigns different private subnets to the two laptops. Is there a way to make these laptops communicate when each one is connected to phone  via USB tethering.   I'm trying to make laptops ping each other in the same way that phones can. I have already tried to set static ip address for usb0 but it doesnt work still.
[image: Setup]

Comment: 192.168.10.20 and 192.168.10.21 tells us that the phones are wirelessly connected to a router. It has nothing to do with the phones having sim cards.